# Should I call super.onPostExecute(result) in Android AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I wonder if it has any meaning to call super.onPostExecute(result) or super.onPreExecute in Android AsyncTask? 
I have been always calling them, but even in Android documentation about AsyncTask ([Android API Reference: AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)) they are omitted. 
So does it make any sense if I call them or not?

Comment: no you can omit the call to the super

Comment: need not but it is better you do

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No, there is no need to call the superclass. If you take a look at the `AsyncTask` source, you will see that the super class does nothing:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
}
```

Comment: but, then how can I return the result, so I can get (`.execute().get();`) it in other activity ?

Answer (score 3):

It has no effect if you call them or not, becase both have empty implementation in `AsyncTask` and they are there only to allow you override them, but does not force you to do that.